# AWS API Gateway Proxy Integration - unable to add URL Path Parameters to OPTIONS method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm adding a HTTP Proxy Integration in API Gateway.

Everything is fine, until I need to handle the catch-all path variable, e.g. /api/users/{id}

In the resource itself, I have added a mandatory "+" sign, i.e. /api/users/{id+}

According to
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-character-error/
each catch-all path variable requires URL Path Parameter defined.
I have added the following one:
Name: id
Mapped from: method.request.path.id

This works fine for all methods but the OPTIONS method for my resource.
For the **OPTIONS** method, the following error pops up:

```
Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.request.path.id
```

Either there is a way to workaround it, or it is a bug...
Any ideas?

BTW, I handle CORS on the server side and would rather not artificially create Mock integrations for OPTIONS method.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Mateusz

Comment: Was the parameter specified in single quotes? Try adding like this 'method.request.path.id'

Comment: Hi Suraj,
Thanks for your response. From the first test it does seem to work! That would be wonderful. Let me dobule check.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much, Suraj!
Note: do that only for the OPTIONS method, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this issue, one of the problem is how we pass the parameter. Try adding it in single quotes if you're not doing that like this -

> 'method.request.path.id'

Comment: This will use `'method.request.path.id'` as a value instead of getting the value from the context.

Comment: use it without quotes i.e, method.request.path.id instead of 'method.request.path.id'